# Use functions of an R package loaded with load_all() in callr::r() and callr::r_bg()

Tags: r, devtools, callr

I'm devoloping an R package and want to run some of the functions in the package under development in the background, using `callr::r()` or `callr::r_bg()`.

As an example, I created a package **mytest** with only one function

```
hello <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

Then loaded the package with `pkgload::load_all()`, the function to load a package in development using **devtools** package. After this, I can run the function in the console but not in the background using `callr::r()`.

```
callr::r(function(){
  mytest::hello()
})
#> Error: callr subprocess failed: there is no package called 'mytest'
#> Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occurred
```

On the other hand, if I install the package and run `library(mytest)`, the code above run without problems

```
callr::r(function(){
  mytest::hello()
})
#> [1] "Hello, world!"
```

Please, any clue why `callr::r()` does not find function `mytest::hello()`?

It looks like `load_all()` is not adding the path to the folder where the source code of the package **mytest** can be found.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution based on an issue in **callr** [GitHub](https://github.com/r-lib/callr/issues/191).

After loading the package **mytest**, that only has the function `hello()` in it as defined in the question, with `devtools::load_all()` the following code works

```
z <- list(mytest::hello)

callr::r(function(z){
  z[[1]]()
}, args = list(z))
#> [1] "Hello, world!"
```

It looks like the function `hello()` in the package loaded with `load_all()` cannot be referred as `mytest::hello()` in `callr::r()` or in `callr::r_bg()` while you can do so if the package was installed and loaded after through `library(mytest)`.

Another option may be to install the new package in the new process started by {callr}:

```
callr::r(function(){
  devtools::install("./")
  mytest::hello()
})
#> [1] "Hello, world!"
```

Please, is there another solution that can be used to iterate the new package development using `load_all()` and use those package functions in a new R session open by {callr}?